# regex matching decimals in an amount

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regex and need to write a regex to match both "100" and "100.00" in an amount value. The last two digits are matched only if these are following a "."

I have tried : ^\d+?(?=([.]{1})\d{2})$  - without any luck

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a lookahead here. You can use an optional non-capture group

```
^\d+(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

Comment: +1, you got that one right.

Comment: what if the delimiter could be either "." OR "," . Thought a could express that by using brackets: ^\d+(?:\[.,]\d{2})?$

Comment: @user878980 Sure, using square brackets allows you multiple characters, so go ahead with that! :)

Comment: somehow it doesnt seems to do the trick -> http://jsfiddle.net/4Ln7A/1/

Comment: @user878980 Not sure why you have the backslash there. See http://jsfiddle.net/4Ln7A/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex: `/^\d+(?:\.\d{2})?$/`

Answer (score 0):

Variation on previous answers

```
^\d{1,8}([\.,]\d{1,2})?$
```

I've found that users will still enter money values as 1.5 when they mean 1.50, so we use a regex to allow for that as well.
The number of decimal places can be adjusted, as can the number of digits before the decimal point